# How to update database when it's empty? Android

Tags: android, database

If you look at my code at the bottom, I have database with column 'used'. If it's 1 it means that it haven't been used, when it is used it set to update the number to 0. But when all of the rows have used number 0, that I would like to update used from 0 to 1 again. How to do that? I do not have a clue. Tried with cd.getCount() but did not work, try some other stuff too but again could not managed to get it to work. So I asking if anyone can help me and tell me what to put into code. Thank you!

This is the error I am getting:

> 02-25 18:46:16.962: E/AndroidRuntime(9728): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

```
public void set(){
   SQLiteDatabase db;
    String vprasanje = "";
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("baza.db",MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor cd=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM vprasanja WHERE kategorija=" + kategorija4 + " AND used = 1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
    cd.moveToFirst();

        vprasanje = cd.getString(cd.getColumnIndex("text"));

        //patch
        String id2 = (cd.getString(cd.getColumnIndex("id")));
        int idd2 = Integer.parseInt(id2);
        db.execSQL("UPDATE vprasanja SET used=0 WHERE id =" + idd2 + ";");


        beseda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        beseda.setText("");
        beseda.setText(vprasanje);

        db.close();
        busy = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so there are a couple of things in your code that need to be fixed. First, you need to check if cursor.moveToFirst() actually happened. You can't try to get strings if there are no records in the database.

First thing then:

```
if(cd.moveToFirst()){

       vprasanje = cd.getString(cd.getColumnIndex("text"));

        //patch
        String id2 = (cd.getString(cd.getColumnIndex("id")));
        int idd2 = Integer.parseInt(id2);
        db.execSQL("UPDATE vprasanja SET used=0 WHERE id =" + idd2 + ";");


        beseda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        beseda.setText("");
        beseda.setText(vprasanje);


        db.close();
        busy = 0;
}
```

However, as long as you dont insert stuff into the database, this will always be false, because there will never be any records in your database. You'll want to insert stuff in case you can't update it:

```
db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO .... SET ... VALUES ...");
```

Comment: Also good to make sure the cursor is not null: `if( cd != null && cd.moveToFirst()){`

Comment: Can I write something like this to update? db.execSQL("UPDATE vprasanja SET used=1 WHERE kategorija=" + kategorija4); @jvrodrigues

Comment: update only works if there's some record already in there. If not you have to insert one.